# Path onPress doesn't work react native svg

Tags: android, react-native, react-native-svg

I'm working on svg map with react-native-svg. On IOS it works fine, but on Android - not. I have Svg tag, nested G tags and Path tags in G. Each Path has onPress attribute, every path is clickable but what I see is very strange: there is such kind of "clickable area". For example, I have:

```
<Svg
      xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
      xmlSpace="preserve"
      width={1242.546}
      height={802.613}
      style={{
        shapeRendering: "geometricPrecision",
        textRendering: "geometricPrecision",
        imageRendering: "optimizeQuality",
        fillRule: "evenodd",
        clipRule: "evenodd",
      }}
      viewBox="0 0 7131.29 4606.4"
    >
      <G>
       <Path onPress={() => alert("this is clickable")} d=""/>
       <Path onPress={() => alert("this path is not clickable")} d=""/>
      </G>
    </Svg>
```

I can click on first path, but I can't click on second. Is there any problem with viewBox or width/height ? Thanks.